# MySQL (pdo) Slow sub query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gets website visit logs from a table. I then join a further 2 tables to this in order to get all of the user's information. At this point the query is fine.

Slow Query:
I then have to use a sub query in order to get the visit logs as of a certain date based on a condition. It is this sub query that causes the entire query to practically grind to a halt. After 30-40 seconds the query will finish.

---

Tables:

- The tables are InnoDB (changing to MyISAM made no difference to performance).
- Table1 has close to 1m records. Table2 has around 250K. Table3 has around 100K. Table4 has around 500K.

---

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS visits , table1.userName, table2.userId, table2.col1, table2.col2, table2.col3, table2.col4, table3.col20
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.userName = table1.userName
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.col2 = table1.col2
    WHERE table1.col1 = 'foo'
    AND table1.Date > (
        SELECT max(a.VisitDate) FROM table4 a
            WHERE  a.userId = table2.userId AND a.col1 = 'bar'
        )
    GROUP BY table1.userName, table1.Date
```

I did not build this data structure and have no option to change it. I am parsing this query into a basic `PDO` function.

Comment: Joins are more efficient than subqueries

Comment: Run EXPLAIN on this query and add the results to your questions

Comment: also, it would be useful to know what indexes you have on the tables

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a inner join (on subselect)

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS visits 
    , table1.userName
    , table2.userId
    , table2.col1
    , table2.col2
    , table2.col3
    , table2.col4
    , table3.col20
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.userName = table1.userName
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.col2 = table1.col2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(a.VisitDate) as max_visit_date FROM table4 a
        WHERE  a.userId = table2.userId AND a.col1 = 'bar'
    )  t  on table1.Date > t.max_visit_date
GROUP BY table1.userName, table1.Date;
```